# Need help LOCKING a Moto G6 XT1925-13 after restoring stock OS

Tags: motorola-moto-g, locked-out, unrooting, motorola

I had semi-bricked / soft-bricked my Motorola Moto G6 smartphone as explained here: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Moto-G6-Moto-G6-Plus-Moto-G6-Play/Need-help-unbricking-a-Moto-G6-XT1925-13-and-restoring-stock-OS/m-p/5013164

And I was stuck trying to install the stock ROM again. Finally, I was able to install the stock ROM onto the device, but I am unable to LOCK it again. The problem I'm facing because of that is that I will not able to upgrade the OS at all.

```
fastboot.exe oem lock
(bootloader) WARNING: This command erases all user data.
(bootloader) Please re-run this command to continue.
OKAY [  0.021s]
Finished. Total time: 0.029s

fastboot.exe oem lock
(bootloader) Check 'Allow OEM Unlock' in Android Settings > Developer
(bootloader) Options
OKAY [  0.029s]
Finished. Total time: 0.058s
```

When I boot into the OS, in the Setting > ... > Developer Options, "OEM unlocking" is already unchecked, as "Bootloader is already unlocked".

In its current state, I cannot upgrade the OS. It's currently at: Android 9.

When trying to check for upgrades, it says:

```
Android version: 9
Current version: PPSS29.55-37-7-10
Security patch level: April 1, 2020
```

Here is what the bootloader displays (I've hidden only the serial number):

```
AP Fastboot Flash Mode (Secure)
BL: MBM-2.1-ali_retail-32ffece02ed-200416
Baseband: M450_23.31.10.89R ALI_INDIADSDS_CUST
Product/Variant: ali XT1925-13 64GB PVT2
Serial Number: [removed]
CPU: SDM450
eMMC: 64GB SAMSUNG RH64AB RV=08 PV=05 FV=0000000000000005
DRAM: 4GB SAMSUNG LP3 DIE:8Gb M5=01 M6=06 M7=00 M8=5F
Console [NULL]: null
Tools Mode Config: DISABLED
Battery OK
flashing_unlocked
Transfer Mode: USB Connected
```

Comment: do yourself a favor and keep it unlocked, you won't solve the OTA issue with this! flash latest ROM from fastboot instead https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3914542

Answer (score 0):

Install Magisk directly after a factory reset before it boots up and the device will be eligible for OTAs. You use 'fastboot boot TWRP.img' instead of flashing TWRP. Make sure to install Magisk Manager and select options to hide Magisk (2 different options) and reboot a couple times to see the effect.
This works on my Moto G6.